# PHP Login page with Indexxeddb

Tags: php, mysql, indexeddb

I am new to PHP and probably never touched any other database except mysql.

My scenario is:

I created a login page with php and mysql database. Also i added "HTML 5 app cache" so it caches all the webpages for offline use. 
What i want now is to let the users login also while offline. Do i need to use indeexeddb so i can store my login credentials ? And if yes ,where do i need to store my user credentials(username, password) for verification?

My login page : [www.lifeofaris.se](http://www.lifeofaris.se)
Its connected with mysql at the moment, but how can make the page so it can log in also while offline?

I will appreciate any information and help

Comment: You can store your login details in either of localstorage, indexeddb, websql, cookie. But note that it will going to be accessible by javascript so it is not secure any way.

Comment: so , all the login details + database must be in a javascript file?

Comment: Yes as you want to run it offline you have to store it in client's browser.

Comment: What are you trying to avoid or accomplish by making all the pages available offline?

Comment: basically i want the user to be able to log in and log out of my website while offliine

Comment: where you ever able to achieve this? I need to achieve the same task and would greatly appareciate any pointers.